# Impact of memory footprint on performance

Tags: .net, multithreading, memory, memory-management

We have a .Net (VS 2012) 64 bit application, running on Windows Server 2012, which loads lots of data in memory to work with it for next 24 - 48 hours. As per our design we prefer to load the data upfront by connecting to the Data source. Net memory footprint of the process goes up to 7-8 GB, which is because we replicate the data for 4 independent threads, which represent the parallel clients, so it like 2 GB of Data per client.

Hardware that we are using is having 128 GB of RAM, 4 CPU (24 Core) processor

I was wondering that does the memory footprint will have an impact on the net performance of the process, like speed of execution, processor utilization etc

Even when we have such a good RAM and the net usage never exceed 60%, will there still be swapping of process pages to HD, thus making it slower, when it is continuously used for 48 hours. Is there some server settings or .Net c# code API, that will help us taking care of performance issues occurring due to memory footprint. We can explicitly tell the system that our process needs lots of memory.

Also let me add, that each parallel client spawns multiple Threadpool threads. to complete Sub task, now the average CPU usage of the process is between 50 - 60%, for the good configuration that we are having, does that mean we need to take steps to figure out the Disk IO bottlenecks, that might be impacting performance

Comment: Your hardware is excellent, but still you have to find out where is the bottleneck. Really memory usage? or disk I/O ?

Answer (score 0):

The first case of when memory consumption matters is a CPU-intensive application that is manipulating a large amount of data.A typical PC can execute an instruction in less than half a nanosecond (0.5 ns). The second case of when (some) memory consumption matters is during an application's cold startup.The operating system tries to mitigate this by caching data from the disk in main memory. This is the reason that an application is faster when launched the second time, during what is called warm startup (the data was cached in faster memory).

Comment: In our case application is certainly CPU intensive, since each parent thread / client spawned, has number Threapool threads invoked to accomplish sub tasks, thus making the average CPU usage between 50 - 60%, which is good enough for the kind of server that we have. Now is there any server setting that can help us with net performance or do I still need to scout for lingering bottlenecks, which can cause lot of Disk IO